# Mouse click on tooltip showed in QSpinBox::validate causes a crash

Tags: c++, qt, qtwidgets

I have a custom SpinBox class that extends a functionality of `QSpinBox`. I'm trying to show a tooltip when the input is correct, that is, show a tooltip in  overriden `QSpinBox::validate(QString &text, int &pos)`. But when I do the mouse click on the tooltip the program crashes.
The crash occures in `QApplicationPrivate::notifyActiveWindowChange(QWindow *previous)`, it looks like Qt tries to set `QTipLabel` (which has already been destroyed) as an active window.

Here is the minimal code to reproduce the crash:

```
// spinbox.h
#include <QSpinBox>
#include <QToolTip>

class SpinBox : public QSpinBox
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit SpinBox(QWidget *parent = nullptr)
        : QSpinBox(parent)
    {}
    ~SpinBox() override = default;

    QValidator::State validate(QString &input, int &pos) const override
    {
        Q_UNUSED(pos);
        int x = input.toInt();
        auto mn = minimum();
        auto mx = maximum();
        if(x >= mn && x <= mx)
        {
            QToolTip::showText(mapToGlobal({0, 0}), QString("Your value fits the range!!!"));
            return QValidator::State::Acceptable;
        }
        else
        {
            QToolTip::hideText();
        }
        return QValidator::State::Invalid;
    }
};

// constructor of the default mainwindow created by qt creator
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    Ui::MainWindow ui;
    ui.setupUi(this);

    auto spin_box = new SpinBox(this);
    spin_box->setRange(1, 200);
}
```

Here is a gif that illustrates the crash: 
[image: GIF]

Thanks in advance!

**UPD.** 
I've found that after clicking on the tooltip, the qtooltip_labelWindow gets focus.
[image]

**UPD2.**
I haven't found the reason of the crash yet, but a workaround that helps me is to install the following event filter to `qApp`:

```
bool eventFilter(QObject* obj, QEvent* e) override
{
    if(obj->objectName().contains("tooltip") && e->type() == QEvent::FocusIn)
    {
      if (auto window = qobject_cast<QWindow*>(obj))
          window->show();
    }
    return QObject::eventFilter(obj, e);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to crash on Linux in Qt 5.11.3.

Comment: Hmm. @K9spud It crashes stably both on win7 and win10. Looks like a qt bug, does not it?

Comment: @MamaBullki If it works in a different OS, or an earlier version, or different from what the documentation says then it is very likely that it is a bug. I recommend reporting it.

Comment: Nah, Qt is pretty solid software. It's probably not a bug in Qt, but a bug in your code. Windows seems to be finicky. I too have had problems that cause a crash in Windows while working fine under Linux, but eventually the problem ultimately turned out to be something I was doing wrong, not Qt. Unfortunately, I'm not running Windows right now to try debugging this.

Comment: A suggestion to try: First, the way you are instantiating the custom SpinBox is odd and not very good. Instead of instantiating it in your code, you should use the Qt Creator form designer to place a QSpinBox on the form, then right click on it and "Promote" it to your custom "SpinBox" class. Now you can use Qt Creator form designer to set up layouts and make things look pretty. The way you've got it now, the SpinBox shows up as it's own window floating on top of the main window, which is bogus and might lead to this odd crash.

Comment: @K9spud in the original app all the controls are placed via Qt Designer. But I've found a workaround to this issue.

Comment: @K9spud I agree that Qt is a pretty solid software but that does not imply that it does not have this type of bugs, maybe before nobody noticed that error and therefore Qt did not have the opportunity to solve it. My recommendation is that the OP report it, I would do it if I had Windows to support my response with tests but I do not have it at this time, so that the solution will serve the entire community.

Comment: @eyllanesc I'll report this isuee to Qt